# Extract DLL and Import DLL (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I want to make portable app that uses the `NAudio` dll. I put the DLL files into Resources and tried this:

```vb
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("\NAudio.dll", My.Resources.NAudio, True)
```

When I run the program (as an exe, not in the debugger), I get this error:

[image: Undhandled Exception window]

I tried DLLimport, no luck. How can I fix this?

Comment: dlls are loaded with the App Domain, usually when the program first launches.

Comment: Oh thank Joel Coehoorn for editing this ^^
also, yeah :(

Comment: I wonder what's the reason/motivation for doing so in the first place? Having a sysadmin background, I can tell you that I would find such a behavior highly suspicious, as would the AV tools used by our organization, i.e. extracting executables and persisting it on the local machine has lots of malware similarities. So even if you get it to work with your supposedly harmless program/DLL, I wouldn't be too surprised  if it would be flagged as malicious/suspicious when run on other machines. I would recommend to stay away from such a practice. IMHO that's more hassle in the long run than benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge)

Worked perfectly.

Also don't need to extract :)